# Question closed as duplicate - reopen request

Tags: support, reopen-request

This is not my question, and I believe it's NOT a duplicate:

[How do you edit Windows10 Directory Junctions (links to folders) from Windows Explorer?](https://superuser.com/questions/1571830/how-do-you-edit-windows10-directory-junctions-links-to-folders-from-windows-ex)

The question in question (*h3h3*) is asking about a GUI (explorer.exe) solution to edit soft links, whereas the [linked question](https://superuser.com/questions/823959/how-to-view-all-the-symbolic-links-junction-points-hard-links-in-a-folder-using) is only talking about the terminal and its options. The linked question is still very relevant, but not quite the same. I believe the question should be reopened.

Comment: It is currently [in review](https://superuser.com/review/reopen/994154) to be reopened. As the answer is "You don't do that in Windows Explorer because it can't handle them" then the duplicate is about as valid as it can be. The question essentially precludes third party programs as well by explicitly asking for solutions ***in*** Windows Explorer. I agree they are different, but having a solution is better than a question with off-topic answers that just gets closed for no other reason. If it were changed to "what extensions can I use" then it would be off topic as a product recommendation.

Comment: I see your points. Thanks for explaining